# How to set height of a a div based on its content?

Tags: javascript, css, tabs, height, html

So I am working on [this](http://ktaftaf.com/dev) website and I have a tabbed section towards the bottom.
I built my tabs using css just like [this](http://css-tricks.com/functional-css-tabs-revisited/). But a problem arose when i wanted the tab content to be different sizes.

I figured if I could target the height of the content I would be able to set the height of .tabs with Javascript.

This is the code I'm using:

```
        $('.tab label').click(function() {
            $('.tab.current').removeClass('current');
            $(this).parent('.tab').addClass('current');
            $('.tabs').height($('.tab.current .content').outerHeight());
        });
```

For some reason its not grabbing the right value. I dont know what Im doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: The tab structure looks like this:

```
           <div class="tabs">

           <div class="tab one current">
                <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
                <label for="tab-1"></label>

                <div class="content">
                    <div class="tab-block first">
                </div><!-- .content -->
           </div><!-- .tab.one -->

           <div class="tab two">
                <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
                <label for="tab-1"></label>

                <div class="content">
                    <div class="tab-block first">
                </div><!-- .content -->
           </div><!-- .tab.two -->

           <div class="tab three">
                <input type="radio" id="tab-1" name="tab-group-1" checked>
                <label for="tab-1"></label>

                <div class="content">
                    <div class="tab-block first">
                </div><!-- .content -->
           </div><!-- .tab.three -->

           </div>
```

The .tabs class Requires a min-height due to the fact that the tabs are being positioned absolutely on top of one another.

So what I would like to do is grab the height of the .content of the .current classand set that height to the .tabs div. so that instead of the height overflowing it will push all content underneath it.

I hope this clears up some of the confusion.

Comment: Well a `<div>` will size itself based on its content as part of its basic behavior. How are you styling the tabs? *edit* checking the site, it's really not clear exactly what you're talking about or what it is that you'd like to be different.

Comment: my content is positioned absolutely. I feel like im there im just unsure as to why my javascript is giving me the incorrect height.

Comment: if my .content has a height set to it I should be able to take that and assign it to the .tabs div

Comment: It took me a while to figure out what you thought was wrong. In Chrome it works fine. So I tried it in Firefox, now I see. Are you on Firefox?

Comment: Being positioned absolutely will not affect the way a `<div>` wraps around its content.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you looking to be able to adjust the size/height of the tabs `.tab > label` and not the content `.content` it contains?  Like a situation where you might have two lines of text in the tab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several things causing this issue.  The main one being CSS3 transition.  The div is animating height when the .current class is being applied.  The javascript is grabbing the value before the CSS3 animation completes which is why you are not getting the correct value.

Instead of using javascript, a cleaner solution would be to apply classes to div.tabs:

```
div.tabs.currentOne {
     height: 250px;
}

div.tabs.currentTwo {
     height: 1022px;
}

div.tabs.currentThree {
     height: 882px;
}
```

And in your javascript:

```
$('.tab label').click(function () {
    var $tabs = $('.tabs');
    $tabs.find('.tab.current').removeClass('current');
    var $currTab = $(this).parent('.tab').addClass('current');

    // remove any one of the classes that we'll apply
    $tabs.removeClass('currentOne currentTwo currentThree');

    // determine which one to apply
    if ($currTab.hasClass('one')) {
        $tabs.addClass('currentOne');
    }
    else if ($currTab.hasClass('two')) {
        $tabs.addClass('currentTwo');
    }
    else if ($currTab.hasClass('three')) {
        $tabs.addClass('currentThree')
    }
});
```

Note that the height of div.tabs has to consider padding and borders of child elements, and height of the labels. It is the height of div.content class + the padding + the 2px bottom padding + 40px for labels.

Also be sure to add the correct class to the tab that will default to visible.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! this worked instantly. 
You might want to remove the extra s in .hassClass for anyone else who reads this.

Comment: I truly appreciate the help. this has been stumping me all day sadly.

Comment: I take it if he changes the content in those tabs he'll have to redefine the height in his CSS?

Comment: That is correct.  But he would already have to do so given the current functionality.  A class with these heights is being applied to the div.content div.  These would have to be changed if he changed the content.  A more dynamic solution for this plugin would require  considerably more javascript.  I don't think he was looking for something as dynamic.

Comment: I am interested in a more dynamic solution, since the content of my tabs (also using the same setup as above, more or less) may change. Any ideas? BTW: great solution if only I could use it...

Answer (score 0):

In your  target class set the height:auto

```
.your_class{
height:auto;
}
```

Add this class to the element you want to assign.

Comment: post some of your relevant code,not all and describe the layout of your html structur and the content that you are talking about.